# Is it possible to send url or form variables o the built-in exp:query tag to build select queries?

Tags: ee3, query-module

Using the supplied EE add-on, is it possible to sen url or form variables or to the builtin exp:query tag to build select queries?

If so, can anyone point me to some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do such things. 
Post example:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(exp_members.join_date), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '<?php echo $this->EE->input->post('date-from'); ?>'
```

You need to turn on php in the template set to parse on input.

You can also load a page where you put your variables in as url segments.

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(exp_members.join_date), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '{segment_3}'
```

GET can also work. `$this->EE->input->get_post('date-from');`